# Dual ubuntu 16.04 can't mount hard drive after a upgrading Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, mount, hard-drive, windows-10

My computer are installing Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 in dual. I worked normal on Ubuntu until I came back Windows 10 and got an update/upgrade after 2 months from the last time.
When I back to Ubuntu, I can not mount my hard drive anymore. The error like bellow:
[image: Can't mount hard drive after upgrading windows 10]

I already turn off fast boot, hibernate.

Any recommendation is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Did you run `chkdsk` from windows?

Comment: Sr @guillermochamorro for late reply. I'm trying your suggestion.
It takes maybe more than 16 hours already. But still not yet done for checking a disk 4.TB.
I will let you know when it done.

Comment: I am feeling terrible now. I got an error like this:
Stage 5: Looking for bad, free clusters ...
  348447505 free clusters processed.
Free space verification is complete.
Correcting errors in the Master File Table (MFT) mirror.
CHKDSK is resetting recovery information...
An unspecified error occurred (6e74667363686b2e 2f56).
PS C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: The solution to solve my problem is: 

1. Move data to another hard drive. 

2. Format the drive. Delete all disk on drive. Convert drive to basic drive. 

3. Move data back to hard drive.